# IBM Worklight - What is worklight server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Worklight and am struggling to understand what exactly is a worklight server.

Where does it reside?

When we build the app it shows in the server console that the app is getting deployed to the Worklight Server.

Initially I thought in order to have an adapter where we invoke the procedure from custom java class, these needed to be deployed to the worklight server. But when I see the app work on real devices where there is no contact with local server where worklight was running , I was shocked to see app gets the data from the custom class even though it was not on some remote worklight server.

Comment: if my answer helped resolve your problem, please mark as answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Google...
2. [IBM Worklight website](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/worklight/)'s and [IBM Worklight Getting Started training materials](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/)
3. [IBM Worklight user documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp)

Worklight Server is the entity that facilitates communication between the client (app) and backend (databases, etc...) using adapters; it also manages application life cycle - allows to block access or notify an app; provides user and device authentication; sends push notifications and web resource updates, etc.

Any request made by the app, be it a connect attempt or adapter request, connects the app with the server.

When you install the Worklight Developer Edition (via the Eclipse marketplace or otherwise), which is an Eclipse plug-in, to your Eclipse... this installation bundles a WAS Liberty profile application server within. Worklight Studio, the IDE and Worklight Server are auto-magically and transparently "installed".

A filesystem-based database is also created within the Worklight-related folders in the Eclipse workspace. Worklight Studio handles the building and deployment of applications and adapters in this development environment.

When you move to a production environment, you install some supported application server (like WAS, Liberty, Tomcat) and deploy to it various Worklight artifacts - the Worklight framework, (the server), project-related files, apps and adapters.

Please read the documentation. Reserve Stackoverflow for programming-related questions.